# Get a file line input from user, read from a file, return only the int value present on the inputted user line number

Tags: python

(Python newbie) Please excuse
How can I build up the code?
Ask for an input from a user and read that specific line from a file and print only the int values

So suppose I have a file "file.txt" as 
1Mbps 10$
2Mbps 20$
3Mbps 30$

Input from user is "1"
(it should store the value of line 1 in a variable)
should return the value 10

Comment: I recommend creating a function to read the file into a list like `[(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)]`. And a function to take a list in that format and write it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those are line-separated, create a read file function:

```
import re

def parse_line(line):
    pattern = r"^(\d+)Mbps (\d+)\$"
    return tuple(map(int, re.search(pattern, line)))

def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        return [parse_line(line) for line in f]
```

And a write file function:

```
def row_to_str(row):
    mbps, price = row
    return f"{mbps}Mbps {price}$"

def write_file(filename, data):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write("\n".join(row_to_str(row) for row in data))
```

Now you can use them as follows:

```
filename = "file.txt"
data = read_file(filename)
mbps = int(input("Input desired mbps: "))
data.append((mbps, mbps * 10))
write_file(filename, data)
```